# Using mysql in koa: co-mysql vs mysql-co?

Tags: mysql, node.js, koa

I'm planning to use `co-mysql` or `mysql-co` in my koa app. Which package should I use?

And why does the `co-mysql` github homepage say:

> yes, you should not use co-mysql! >_<

Is there some known security problem? Should I use `mysql-co` instead?

https://github.com/coderhaoxin/co-mysql

https://github.com/sidorares/mysql-co

Comment: You could always open an issue there and ask the repository owner directly.

Answer (score 0):

For starters any co module doesn't do anything special. What you should look for is the module behind that they wrap so that they are compatible with generators. In this case one uses mysql and the other uses mysql2.

According to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/sidorares/5500553) mysql2 performs much faster queries. They are both updated at the same rate yet the owner of mysql2 has let his build fail, which is a little worrying. My recommendation is to pick either of the modules and if you run into problems then try switching. The syntax is pretty much identical so you won't have to change much code if you do end up switching. There's nothing wrong with experimenting.